# Warning number guide in Visual C# 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What is a good resource for finding out the warning numbers in Visual C# 2008. I found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wtxwb6k.aspx but it's very hard to sort through the warning numbers.

I am trying to figure out which warning number to use for the warning disable pragma:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx

Specifically, I am trying to find the one related to Missing XML comments for publicly visible types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's CS1591. Just press F1 on the warning location to view MSDN documentation for it.

You can resolve this specific warning either by:

- Reducing warning level (it's a level 4 warning)
- Removing `/doc` switch (which will stop XML file generation)
- Disable the warning using `#pragma` directive
- Disable the warning using `/nowarn:1591` switch

Comment: F1 did not not bring up the error help for me but right clicking on the error and selecting "Show Error Help" brought it up.

Comment: @RyanTM: Moving the cursor somewhere **in code** that is marked by warning lines and pressing F1 will take you to the error/warning.

Answer (score 2):

To find warning numbers in Visual Studio, build your project and then look for the warning numbers in the Output window.

Comment: -1: thanks for trying to help, but that's not the information he was looking for. The question was about the _meaning_ of the warning numbers.

Comment: Question was NOT about the meaning of Warning number. It is about getting the warning # about a particular warning and then using that warning # to disable the warning using #pragma directive.

Comment: Then perhaps you should have said so.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the full list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx but it's in a very useless format...